# Prokaryote or just a small worm

Tags: species-identification, microbiology

In the following photos can be seen a thread-like (almost like longkou vermicelli) things. At first I was convinced that it was cyanobacteria, however a classmate said it look more like a little worm, and other person said it look like it was probably nothing (nor prokaryote nor worm). I can't find a way to settle what it is, how can I know?

[image]

Zoom 40x

This is from another sample
[image]

---

EDIT:
Could the first one be lyngbya? I found [this](http://cfb.unh.edu/phycokey/Choices/Cyanobacteria/cyano_filaments/cyano_unbranched_fil/untapered_filaments/no_heterocysts/vis_sheath/LYNGBYA/Lyngbya_Image_page.htm) website and the second to last picture kind of looks like what it is in my picture:[image]

And also could my second picture depict nostoc bacteria?

Comment: The first picture shows something different than the two following picture, doesn't it? Did it move? What is the zoom? You might want to review a little bit your knowledge about the diversity of eukaryotes (incl. unicellular eukaryotes).

Comment: If it doesnt have a mouth and anus and organs it's not a worm.

Comment: @Remi.b I added that the zoom is 40x. It didn't move, at least not enough for being noticeable. I agree that I need to study about the diversity of single celled organisms, but why do you say eukaryotes? is that a hint? I thought it had to be a procaryote since it sort of look like a very long bacillus. Also, I was convinced it was cyanobacteria, but now I doubt it

Comment: What was the source of these creatures?

Comment: @Tytoalba Pond water... very dirty pond water

Comment: @AnaGalois Because you talk about worms! A worm is a eukaryote. You uploaded twice the same picture. The first picture was maybe the most interesting you might want to make sure to upload it as well.

Comment: @Remi.b Right!!! I'm sorry. Yes  I'll upload it again, however it is from a different sample

Answer (score 3):

This would be a suggestion rather than a precise answer.

Your sample being pond water a highly probable candidate of the first two photographs would be *[Euglena sp.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euglena)*, though the red eyespot is not visible.

They are freshwater [Excavates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Excavata)   and according to [Washington State Lake Protection Association](http://www.walpa.org/waterline/june-2012/algae-can-function-as-indicators-of-water-pollution/) a common pollution-tolerant genus in Washington water bodies.

[image]

Another picture reference: [A website](http://www.funsci.com/fun3_en/guide/guide1/micro1_en.htm)

Comment: I think Euglena is a good guess for one of the things in the picture, but I don't think that's what OP meant by "like longkou vermicelli"

Comment: :P I missed that.

Comment: Thank you. I also added another picture I found on the web, perhaps those two are related?